# Combinig output of 2 function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, textfield

I am relatively new to Javascript (biopython background) and I am trying to add a simple feature to a website.

In essence, I need to accept user input for 4 types of menus (*check boxes*) and then multiply the sum of the values ($) of selected menus by the number of days and number of people (*user inputs using text fields*).

Below are HTML and Javascript parts of the code

```js
function multiply() {
  var n_ppl = document.getElementsByName('people')[0].value;
  var n_days = document.getElementsByName('days')[0].value;
  return var out = n_ppl * n_days; 
}
  
function totalIt() {
  var n_ppl = document.getElementsByName('people')[0].value;
  var n_days = document.getElementsByName('days')[0].value;
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseInt(input[i].value);
    }
  return var price = total
}

  // not sure how can I get - var final = total * out
  // after I get it I can finally do - document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + final.toFixed(2);
```

```html
<br> Breakfast <input name="product" value="12" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" /> <br>
<br> First Meal <input name="product" value="20" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" /> <br>
<br> Second Meal <input name="product" value="15" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" /> <br>
<br> Craft Service <input name="product" value="10" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" /> <br>
<br> Number of People <input type="text" name="people"> <br>
<br> Number of Days <input type="text" name="days"> <br>
<br> Total: <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="total" />
```

I apologize to all web developers for my pythonic style in advance.

I should also mention that both functions work perfectly fine separately but even without trying to multiply their outputs (i.e. even if their code is present next to each other), nothing works.
I will be really grateful for your help!

Comment: From the [`java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) ...*". From the [`javascript` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*JavaScript (**not to be confused with Java**) ...*"

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different languages.  There is no actual mention of Java in your question, so you should not tag it `[java]`.  (Why? Because incorrect tagging wastes peoples' time.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "</br>" was a typo. And type should be "text" too, apologies

Comment: You should use `<label>`s

Comment: `return var price = total` <-- not sure where you learned that

Comment: `return var price = total` is not valid JavaScript - simply do `return total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need only **one function** to iterate over your inputs.
- Do not use inline JavaScript it's sign of bad coding habits, and makes the application hard to debug. Keep your JS in one place and **make use of `Element.addEventListener()`**
- Use `Node.querySelector()` and `Node.querySelectorAll()`
- Use `name="product[]"` syntax when handling similar names. This will be submitted to the backend as an array of values.
- You can **use Array.prototype.reduce()** to reduce (accumulate) all your `'[name="product[]"]:checked'` chechboxes values to a single integer
- Place your `<script>` code  right **before the closing `</body>` tag**

```js
const EL_menu  = document.querySelector("#menu");

const calcPrice = evt => {

  const price = [...EL_menu.querySelectorAll('[name="product[]"]:checked')]
    .reduce((n, el) => (n += +el.value, n), 0);
    
  const nPers = +EL_menu.querySelector('[name="people"]').value || 1;
  const nDays = +EL_menu.querySelector('[name="days"]').value || 1;
  const total = price * nPers * nDays;
  
  EL_menu.querySelector("[name=total]").value = `\$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
}

EL_menu.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('input', calcPrice));
```

```css
#menu label { display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="12"> Breakfast</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="20"> First Meal</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="15"> Second Meal</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="10"> Craft Service</label>
  <label><input type="number" name="people" value="1" min="1"> Number of People</label>
  <label><input type="number" name="days" value="1" min="1"> Number of Days</label><br>
  Total: <input type="text" name="total" value="$0.00" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help @RokoC.Buljan! I have a long way to learn..
But I still have a trivial issue. When I run code snippet here, it works perfectly fine but when I add it to my website, functionality disappears. What can cause this?

Comment: You're welcome @duda13 Hm, how could I know? Open Developer console and read the errors if you have any. If you have no errors in console, make sure you copied the example properly, specially the HTML part.

Comment: no errors in Developer console. Seems like copied HTML correctly too. I will add code in an answer to my question..

Comment: @duda13 your issue is totally simple. JS code should go right before the **closing body tag**  `</body>` to make sure the DOM is read and ready to be manipulated. If you tell the JS interpreter *"hey, go find this element"* - the JS interpreter will stop it's execution and not find any Element in the current DOM. If instead you let the DOM parser to finish it's parsing and construct the DOM tree, JS will than know everything about every element.

Comment: @duda13 See this [jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/bumumes/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Okay, I finally got it. Thanks a lot!